# AVAudioSession properties after Initializing AUGraph

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudiosession

To start a call, our VOIP app sets up an AVAudioSession, then builds, initializes and runs an AUGraph.

During the call, we allow the user to switch back and forth between a speakerphone mode using code such as:

```
avSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions categoryOptions = [avSession categoryOptions];
categoryOptions |= AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker;
NSLog(@"AudioService:setSpeaker:setProperty:DefaultToSpeaker=1 categoryOptions = %lx", (unsigned long)categoryOptions);
BOOL success = [avSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:categoryOptions error:&error];
```

Which works just fine. But if we try to certain AVAudioSession queries after the AUGraph has been initialized, for example:

```
    AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription *myInputDataSource = [avSession inputDataSource];
```

the result is null. Running the same line of code BEFORE we execute the AUGraphInitialize gives the correct non-null result. Can anyone explain what is going on here and how to properly access AVAudioSession properties/methods while using AUGraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior per the [developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/inputDataSource) documentation, `inputDataSource` should return `nil` if it is not possible to switch sources. So Apple is really not letting anything bad happen via a mis-config, but a nil source can also give the wrong idea. Hope this helps.

```
Discussion
The value of this property is nil if switching between multiple input
sources is not currently possible. This feature is supported only on
certain devices and peripherals–for example, on an iPhone equipped with
both front- and rear-facing microphones.
```

Comment: Thanks, it somewhat begs the question though... once a call starts I can re-route from the Receiver to the Speaker with the AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker. But this has the side effect of also switching the microphone from the "Bottom" mic to the "Front" mic. If while the call is in progress, I cannot get to the other microphones (e.g. via inputDataSource, et al), then seems like I cannot really take advantage of the features (e.g. cardioid directional mic).

Comment: You raise a good point. Because these APIs are in development (according to the doc headers), I would file a radar(https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/), with all the details, code snippets and conditions to repro "not taking advantage" of the hw.

Comment: Additional experimentation shows that I do NOT have this problem when using the RemoteIO Audio Unit, only when using the Voice Processing IO Unit. My experience is suggesting that when VPIO is in use, Apple locks down/hardwires certain features in the audio processing path, likely to ensure that echo cancelation and other advanced features will work.